# Looking to start a loop through a column but starting at a specific row? -Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I am trying to run code where if it finds bold characters in a specific column, it will insert a row above it. However, I am struggling to start the loop at a specific row. Here is what I have:

```
Sub Cisco_IfBold_Test()
'
' Cisco_IfBold_Test Macro
'

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    lLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For lRow = lLastRow To 2 Step -1
     If Cells(lRow, "A").Font.Bold = True Then
     Cells(lRow, "A").EntireRow.Insert
     
     End If
    Next lRow
    End Sub
```

I am sure it is an easy fix but I am confusing myself with starting at a row, but needing the loop through the column. Thank you for any help!

Comment: What row are you trying to start at?

Comment: 19, I think I figured it out by changing the 2. I am very new so took me a while.

But now stuck trying to add more stuff to the loop if you wouldn't mind helping?

Comment: Correct, the `2` is what needs to be edited. This site works on a `1 Question N Answers` basis. A new issue deserves a new post

Comment: In this example you are starting at lLastRow and ending at row 2, as indicated by the step -1.